# .HTACCESS RewriteRule force default page to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess

I did a lot of searching on this, and just couldn't quite find the right answer.  A lot of things got me close, but nothing worked like I wanted it to.

I'm working on a site where, because of an external JQuery add-on library, I need to force certain pages to be HTTP.  Certain other pages (for shopping, etc) need to be HTTPS.

So far in my .HTACCESS file I have:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^(index|event)\.php$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works perfectly when the user goes to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php
```

But doesn't redirect when they go to

```
https://www.example.com/
```

Any suggestions on how to catch that last instance?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match landing page tweak your regex to match empty URI also like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^80$
RewriteRule ^((index|event)\.php)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```